# How to parse date without using Local Time Zone?

Tags: android, date, kotlin, simpledateformat

From Server I get following values:

```
epochMillis=1556532279322
iso8601=2019-04-29T10:04:39.322Z
```

When I do  `serverTimeDateFormat.parse(iso8601)`, I get as a result `Mon Apr 29 10:04:39 GMT+02:00 2019`

and for `serverTimeDateFormat.parse(iso8601).time`, the result is `1556525079322`, which is different from what I get from the server (2 hours behind from UNIX time), while I am in timeZone + 2 hours.

When I format it back with `serverTimeDatFormat.format(1556525079322)`, the result is `2019-04-29T10:04:39.322Z`
I understand that `SimpleDateFormat` is using local timezone, but why is the result 2 hours behind and how can I parse the `Date` without taking into account timezone? I don't understand the logic of all this.

My code:

```
private val serverTimeDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",Locale.ENGLISH)
val iso8601 = "2019-04-29T10:04:39.322Z" 
val epochMillis = 1556532279322
serverTimeDateFormat.parse(iso8601).time
```

Comment: Show us your code with a little explanation, please...

Comment: Instead of `'Z'` in your pattern, try putting `XXX` (without quotes).

Comment: Thank you @TiiJ7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies with the pattern for your SimpleDateFormat. At the end, you have `'Z'`, which indicates there should be a literal "Z" in the date string to be parsed. However, the "Z" at the end of the date has a special meaning, namely [it signifies the UTC timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)). Hence, you should parse it as a timezone designator so that the correct date value will be obtained. You can do this with the pattern `XXX` (See [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)).

```
private val serverTimeDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX",Locale.ENGLISH)
val iso8601 = "2019-04-29T10:04:39.322Z" 
print( serverTimeDateFormat.parse(iso8601).time ) // 1556532279322
```

[Runnable example on pl.kotl.in](https://pl.kotl.in/FfnPFEqPm)

---

**Addendum**: While the above code should work for you, if at all possible, you should consider adding ThreeTen Android Backport to your project. This will give you access to the newer time classes added by JSR310 to Java/Kotlin (Also available by default in [Android API >=26](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary)). The classes have generally easier API, and use ISO8601 by default, so you wouldn't need any formatter at all:

```
print( ZonedDateTime.parse(iso8601).toInstant().toEpochMilli() )
```

Answer (score 1):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using *terrible* date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

### `Date::toString` lies

> why is the result 2 hours behind

It is not actually two hours behind.

The problem is that while a  `java.util.Date` represents a moment in UTC, its `toString` method dynamically applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating the text representing the value of the date-time object. While well-intentioned, this anti-feature confusingly creates the illusion of the `Date` object having that time zone.

In other words, `Date::toString` lies. One of many poor design decisions found in these legacy classes. And one of many reasons to never use these legacy classes.

## *java.time*

### `Instant`

Parse your count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC as a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1556532279322 );
```

Your other input, a standard ISO 8601 string, can also be parsed as an instant.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2019-04-29T10:04:39.322Z" ) ;
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

To see the same moment through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone), apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ) ;
```

Both the `instant` and `zdt` objects represent the same simultaneous moment. Two ways of reading the same moment, as two people conversing on the phone in Iceland and Québec would each see a different time on the clock on the wall while glancing simultaneously.